# the while loop isn't terminating and the program isn't taking the next input

Tags: python

i want to take the next input but the program runs just once and the while loop doesn't terminate leading to runtime exceed(I have mentioned in the code where i am terminating the while loop)

k>1 always and the elif condition isn't becoming an infy loop rather the code is executing perfect for just 1 input

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
  k=int(input())
  b=2
  c=0
  i=1
  while i>0:
    if k>=2:
      k-=b
      b+=3
    elif k<0:
      b-=3
      k+=b
      c+=1
    else:
      c+=1
      i=0     {#here i am trying to make i=0 and terminate the while loop and take the next input}
  print(c)
```

Comment: The `elif k<0` part is potentially an infinite loop.  `b-=3` can produce negative numbers, in which case `k+=b` makes `k` *even more negative than it already is*.  (Also note that your use of the variable `i` is a bit strange - the normal way of getting out of a `while` loop due to a condition is a `break` statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PATH 1**

I will show you 1 path that makes an infinite cycle.

Supose that you choose `k = -1`:

1:  `while i>0: # i=1`

2:  `elif k<0: # k=-1`

3: `b-=3  # b was equal to 2, so gonna be -1`

4: `k+=b  # k now will be -2`

5:  `while i>0: # i=1`

6:  `elif k<0:  # k=-2`

7: `b-=3  # b was equal to -1, so gonna be -4`

8: `k+=b # k now will be -6`

And go on...

The cycle will never finish in that way

---

**PATH 2**

For `k` equal to 4:

1:  `while i>0: # i=1`

2:  `if k>=2: # k=4`

3: `k-=b  # b=2, so k will be 2`

4: `b+=3  # b will be 5`

5:  `while i>0: # i=1`

6:  `if k>=2: # k=2`

7: `k-=b  # b=5, so k will be -3`

8: `b+=3  # b will be 8`

9:  `while i>0: # i=1`

10: `elif k<0:  # k = -3`

11:  `b-=3  # b was equal to 8, so will be 5`

12: `k+=b # k was equal to -3, so will be 2`

And now it loops for sentence `5` -> Cycle infinite again

---

I can't suggest you what you have to do if you didn't explain. I can only explain why your solution is not right.

Comment: sorry, i didnt mention that k >1 always

Comment: In which `k` value, the cycle goes infinite?

Comment: `for _ in range(int(input())):` i give input as 2 so for 2 independent cases it needs to work right, it doesnt, rather it just works for the first input

Comment: Updated with a new PATH for k > 1, more concrete, k=4

Comment: It happens for more cases, like `k` equals to 5 and 6. So, you have to change your code, that's not totally right

Answer (score -1):

Could you edit your question with the entire Traceback? The code is runs fine on my machine:

```
for _ in range(int(input('range? '))):
  k=int(input('k? '))
  b=2
  c=0
  i=1
  while i>0:
    if k>=2:
      k-=b
      b+=3
    elif k<0:
      b-=3
      k+=b
      c+=1
    else:
      c+=1
      i=0
  print(f'c:{c}')


> range? 3
> k? 2
> c:1
> k? 2
> c:1
> k? 3
> c:1
```

Comment: you are giving one input at  time i need to rerun the code multiple times( like t times) on new input